# Create spyscroll html from single javascript array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I want to create a  spyscroll-menu with unlimited amounts of submenu's and items from a single array. I have a function which creates an array based on `<h>` tags. So for example if i have content with the following `<h>` tags:

```
<div id="whitepaper">
    <h2></h2>
    <h3></h3>
    <h3></h3>
    <h4></h4>
    <h3></h3>
    <h2></h2>
    <h3></h3>
</div>
```

That function is simply this:

```
$(function() {
    let list = [];
    document.querySelectorAll('#whitepaper *').forEach(function(node) {
        let element = $(node);
        if (element.is('h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6')) {
            let tag = element.prop("tagName");
            let index = parseInt(element.prop("tagName").substring(1)) - 2;
            list.push(index);
        }
    });
});
```

My desired output would be:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <h2>h2</h2>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <h3>h3</h3>
            </li>
            <li>
                <h3>h3</h3>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <h4>h4</h4>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <h3>h3</h3>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li>
        <h2>h2</h2>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <h3>h3</h3>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

But i cant really figure this one out. This is what i'm already trying:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        let list = [];
        document.querySelectorAll('#whitepaper *').forEach(function(node) {
            let element = $(node);
            if (element.is('h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6')) {
                let tag = element.prop("tagName");
                let index = parseInt(element.prop("tagName").substring(1)) - 2;
                list.push(index);
            }
        });

        function makeArray(keys, value) {
            let variable = new Array();
            let index = keys.shift();
            if (!keys.length) {
                variable[index] = value;
            } else {
                variable[index] = makeArray(keys, value);
            }
            console.log(variable[index]);
            return variable;
        }

        let value = 'some value';
        let result = makeArray(list, value);

        var dump = JSON.stringify(result, null, 4);
        $('#dump').html(dump)
    });
</script>
<pre id="dump"></pre>

<div id="whitepaper">
    <h2></h2>
    <h3></h3>
    <h3></h3>
    <h4></h4>
    <h3></h3>
    <h2></h2>
    <h3></h3>
</div>
```

Anyone who can push me in the right direction?

Comment: the logic is not clear , what is the result if you have h2,h2,h3,h2.             h2 is always on top of menu?

Comment: Hi, then the result is `<ul>
  <li>h2</li>
    <li>
        <h2>h2</h2>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <h3>h3</h3>
            </li>
      </ul>
      <li>h2</li>
</ul>`

Comment: It is true that the `<h2>` is always the startpoint. There are no `<h1>` tags in my case.

Comment: you couldnt have h2,h4...     you have always one level of difference max  h2,h3  or h3,h4 but never h2,h4?

Comment: @Frenchy that is correct. It is always 1 level difference.

Comment: its sort of summary..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228008/discussion-between-gobbin-and-frenchy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just create the html code by testing the value with the precedent value

```js
 let list = [];
  document.querySelectorAll('#whitepaper *').forEach(function(node) {
      let element = $(node);
      if (element.is('h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6')) {
          let tag = element.prop("tagName");
          let index = parseInt(element.prop("tagName").substring(1));
          list.push(index);
      }
  });

  let htmlcode = "<ul><li>"
  var listlg = list.length;
  for (i = 0; i < listlg; ++i) {
    var h = "h" + list[i];
    var hd = "<" + h + ">";
    var he = "<" + h + "/>";

    if( i == 0){
      htmlcode += hd + h + he;
      continue;
    }
    

    if(list[i] == list[i-1] ){
      htmlcode += "</li><li>" + hd + h + he;
      continue;
    }

    if(list[i] > list[i-1] ){
      htmlcode += "<ul><li>" + hd + h + he;
      continue;
    }

    if (list[i] < list[i - 1]) {
      if (list[i] != 2) {
        htmlcode += "</li></ul></li><li>" + hd + h + he;
      }else{
        var dif = list[i -1] - list[i] + 1;
        htmlcode += "</li></ul>".repeat(dif) + "<ul><li>" + hd + h + he;
      }
    }
    
  }
  
  var dif = list[listlg -1] - 1;
  htmlcode += "</li></ul>".repeat(dif);
  $('#dump').html(htmlcode);
  console.log('html ' + htmlcode);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="whitepaper">
    <h2></h2>
    <h3></h3>
    <h3></h3>
    <h4></h4>
    <h3></h3>
    <h2></h2>
    <h3></h3>
</div>
<pre id="dump"></pre>
```